# Cheerio Web Scrape how to webscrape inside of a webscrape

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, cheerio

I have a specific page that I have scraped some data from, but to gather more information I need to follow another href link to gather more data for that specific item, and I don't know how.

Here is what I have so far:

```
       router.get("/:id",function(req,res){
       var url = "www.someurl.com"

       request(url, function (error, response, html){
       if (!error && response.statusCode == 200){
        $ = cheerio.load(html);

       $('div.ProductDetails').each(function(){// function for details
          var self = this;
          var a = $(this).children().children();
          details = a.attr('href');

          details = {
          details:details
      };
```

This gives me a link to the details section with the actual details. I just need to know how to do a scrape inside of a scrape.

Answer (score 1):

The same way you did the first time, `details.details` is the url in the `<a>` tag.

So you need to make a request to that url

`request(details.details, function(err, res, html) { /* code */ })`

and then use cheerio to extract data.

Comment: im was trying to do it this way by doing another request to details but im getting an error saying details is not defined. i need a way to set details into the router function.